# Spark2 Dataset<Row> saveAsTable didn't update HIVE metadata

Tags: apache-spark, hive, hadoop2

I'm using spark 2.1.0, here's the simplest code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    SparkSession spark = SparkSession.builder().enableHiveSupport().appName("Spark Test").getOrCreate();
    List<Employee> employees = ImmutableList.of(new Employee("a"), new Employee("b"), new Employee("c"));
    Dataset<Row> df = spark.createDataFrame(employees, Employee.class);
    df.write().saveAsTable("Employee_" + new Random().nextInt(100));
}
```

I submit it by spark-submit CLI:

```
spark-submit --class test.spark.Driver --master yarn --deploy-mode cluster
```

I can see the data is persisted on HDFS: `/usr/hive/warehouse/Employee_23`, but when I run `spark.sql("select * from Employee_23")`, got error:

```
Table or view not found
```

I can see in hive metastore database, there's no record in TBLS table.

But if I open `spark-shell` to execute similar code, it works.

Is this happening because of `spark-submit`? Please help.

Comment: Are you using existing Hive metastore  connection in your code ?

Comment: Yes, there's hive-site.xml in spark/conf folder, the connection setting is right.

Comment: I just tried using different deploy-mode: client (previous is cluster), the table registered in hive metastore. When using cluster, which means when driver run on yarn, connected to different hive metastore ??

Comment: yes, therefore you need to maintain your connection to the same metastore.

Comment: when connecting with external datasource path option is good in Spark 2.1.  `df.write.option("path", "/some/path").saveAsTable("t")`

Comment: Thanks very much for your help Sandeep.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out the reason, my hadoop and spark are deployed in different docker containers, I put hive-site.xml in spark container, so it works when I run spark-shell.

But when depoly mode is "cluster", driver is running on yarn, so this driver can't see hive-site.xml in spark container, the solution is put hive-site.xml into hadoop conf folder (etc/hadoop).